# Match regex only if same string is found twice

Tags: java, regex

I am using Cisco Prime Infrastrucure, which uses the Java regex engine. I would like to have a regex that only matches, if a certain string is found exactly twice in a particular configuration (text output)

I tried matching the corresponding area, set it in a group and then try to rematch the exact same thing with a backtrack:

```
(at \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} CET \D{3} \D{3} \d+ \d{4} by \D{6})\1
```

`\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group`

So basically, if i run the regex against following text:

```
Current configuration : 11518 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 12:48:00 CET Thu Jan 3 2019 by admjos
! NVRAM config last updated at 12:48:00 CET Thu Jan 3 2019 by admjos
!
```

I should get a match, because they are identical. But if I run it against:

```
Current configuration : 11524 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 10:40:46 CET Wed Jan 16 2019 by admjos
! NVRAM config last updated at 12:48:02 CET Thu Jan 3 2019 by admjos
!
```

I shouldn't get a match, cause the two lines differ. Hope something like this is even possible within regex. I do not have the possibility to use functions for this.

Comment: Add `.*\n.*` before `\1`

Comment: WTF, you just answered a problem i have dealt with for hours in just 2 min... It works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @MarioJost he is a legend of regex.

Comment: @MarioJost I [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219907/3832970) with explanation and a demo below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
String regex = "(at \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} CET \\D{3} \\D{3} \\d+ \\d{4} by \\D{6}).*\\R.*\\1";
                                                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rmIfHE/2).

The `.*\n.*` will additionally match the whole rest of the line where Group 1 pattern matched, then a line break char sequence (`\R`), then again any 0+ chars other than line break chars and then a substring that is exactly the same as the text captured into Group 1.

Note that you may match the first `at` as a whole word using `\b`:

```
String regex = "\\b(at \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} CET \\D{3} \\D{3} \\d+ \\d{4} by \\D{6}).*\\R.*\\1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what it is exactly you are trying to do but here is the solution I came up with.

`(at [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*)\n.*\1`

Let me break down step by step what is happening at most basic level I can.

`(` start capture group
`at` matches exactly "at "
`[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` matches the date in the format you have above
`.*` match 0 or more of any character (excluding new line)
`)` end capture group
`\n` match a line break character
`.*` match 0 or more of any character (excluding new line)
`\1` match capture group 1

So in short what this will do is match if you have two lines in a row which are excatly the same after the at date part of the line.